# Rendering Table Data

Tags: javascript, html

i am using a table in which i am sending data from a form by using a javascript
the code is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span*">
        <table id="production" class="table table-bordered" style="margin:10px auto;border:1px solid #999;width:95%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="col" width="200">Product Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="col" width="300">Product Quantity</td>
               </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div></div>

<form name="order" id="order">
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <label for="prodname">Product Name:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input id="prodname" name="product name" type="text" />
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
          <label for="prodquantity">Product Quanitity:</label>
         </td>
         <td>
           <input id="prodquantity" name="product quantity" type="text" />
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
<button type="button" onClick="updateForm();"/>Add</button>
</form>
```

And the javascript code is :

```
function updateForm() {
   var prdn = document.getElementById("prodname").value;
   var prdq = document.getElementById("prodquantity").value;
   var table=document.getElementById("production");
   var row=table.insertRow(-1);
   var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
   cell1.innerHTML=prdn;
   cell2.innerHTML=prdq;                
}
```

How can I retrieve the elements of two columns in two rows instead of columns ?

Comment: cannot understand.. can u post a jsfiddle or explain more your problem

Comment: How can you retrieve what of what of... what do you want exactly?

Comment: i need the data after entering to appearing vertically in columns  (in front of the heading in table), while currently they are appearing in the third row (horizontally), this is my fiddle.....http://jsfiddle.net/krishkam2610/3e7rh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem right, you want to display the data on 2 rows instead of 2 columns.

```
<table id="production">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</table>

function updateForm() {
   var prdn = document.getElementById("prodname").value;
   var prdq = document.getElementById("prodquantity").value;
   var table=document.getElementById("production");
   var rows=table.rows;
   var cell1=rows[0].insertCell(-1);
   var cell2=rows[1].insertCell(-1);
   cell1.innerHTML=prdn;
   cell2.innerHTML=prdq;                
}
```

This is provided you can change your HTML structure. What i did was:

- structure the table as two rows with the first element in each row as a table header.
- get the rows of the table
- for each row append a cell at the end
- set the content of the cell

Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/QzcZN/

Comment: can you show me by example, m sorry for being to novice to scripting.

Comment: Andrei thanx for it, it really helped me achieved what i needed.

Comment: Andrei i am once again needing your help, can you help me understand how to insert the productname and productquanity from the HTML form in the second column of the table, not cell.http://jsfiddle.net/krishkam2610/3e7rh/6/

Comment: I can't really understand how this is different from what I answered previously. Here is what i understood: http://jsfiddle.net/3e7rh/7/ If this is now what you answered than explain better or ask other question since this one was answered :)

Comment: Andrei according to what you what you suggested in the previous answer the data from the HTML form was incrementing the cell, and not the value was inserting the separate column, suppose i have created a table of three columns and three rows, first column is header, second is empty and third is predefined, now i want to enter the value in the second column, i have raised this question again, my updated fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/3e7rh/2/ and the question raised here again today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358766/handling-the-table-from-a-html-form-with-javascript

Comment: Aha, I understood now I think, I will answer it there.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the selector with id and found the table , get the rows and per every row get the TD , like this example...

http://fiddle.jshell.net/beME9/show/