# Handling the table from a html form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table id="production">

    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <td></td>
        <td>elementsdefined</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <td></td>
        <td>elementsdefined</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Product Name:


            


            


                


            


        


        


            


                Product Quanitity:


            


            


                


            


        


    


    


    Add

```
function updateForm() {

    var prdn = document.getElementById("prodname").value;
    var prdq = document.getElementById("prodquantity").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("production");
    var rows = table.rows;
    var cell1 = rows[0].insertCell(-1);
    var cell2 = rows[1].insertCell(-1);

    cell1.innerHTML = prdn;
    cell2.innerHTML = prdq;

}
```

I need someone help me understand how I can insert data in separate column in database; suppose I have a table of three rows and three columns, columns are created by using td tags, now in the first and last columns elements are predefined and so any data should insert in the second column of the table after clicking the button. because the code above is inserting the data in raw cells by default.

i am adding the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/3e7rh/2/

Comment: i cant see any element with the id "prodname" or "prodquantity"

Comment: I am getting what do you want to achieve exactly? Can you tell us exactly what you want ?

Comment: somebody please help me how do i get the desired result, how to insert the prodname and prodquantity from the HTML form into the second column of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here, you need to add in the last - 1 column.

http://jsfiddle.net/3e7rh/8/

```
function updateForm() {
    var prdn = document.getElementById("prodname").value;
   var prdq = document.getElementById("prodquantity").value;
   var table=document.getElementById("production");
   var rows=table.rows;
   var cell1=rows[0].insertCell(rows[0].cells.length - 1);
   var cell2=rows[1].insertCell(rows[1].cells.length - 1);
   cell1.innerHTML=prdn;
   cell2.innerHTML=prdq;
}
```

#### Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/3e7rh/10/

```
function updateForm() {
    var prdn = document.getElementById("prodname").value;
   var prdq = document.getElementById("prodquantity").value;
   var table=document.getElementById("production");
   var rows=table.rows;
   var cell1=rows[0].cells[1].textContent=prdn;
   var cell2=rows[1].cells[1].textContent=prdq;
}
```

Comment: Andrei is it any impossible thing to insert the value in column withing td tags insteading of incrementing the cells.

Comment: Bcause what i am trying to achieve is not what this code is doing, however this pretty close to solution.

Comment: Ok, so you don't want to add a new column, just use the second column ?

Comment: Andrei this is what i exactly needed. helping me to understand coding. thanx truly.

Answer (score 0):

Get the table. Iterate over all rows and fill in the first td (Because you are using th as the first one)

```
   var table = document.getElementById("production")
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        columns = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
      columns[0].textContent="text"; //First Td second column in your case
    }
```

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/7xs6v/1/

I am assuming you want to fill the same text in every first td(second column). If you want individual then you can use the index specificallyinstead of iterating over for loop

Comment: yes i want exactly similar but how with using the HTML form?

Comment: Not understanding whether you are putting the table into form or you want to fill out some data. Please send some ore details. Also update the same in the question above

Comment: Ankur Aggarwal i am inserting the data from a HTML form to table, data should insert in the second column of the table, if you still have problem in understanding please ask.

Comment: You want to add both prodName and prodquantity into second column?

Comment: Yes i want to add both in the second column.

Comment: Ankur Aggarwal now i see that you have understood the actual requirment, can you help me with the required script to bring out the desired output in javascript